# the same msg type of multiple topic names can use only one callback on ros2?

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have  `/camera_1`,  `/camera_2`,  `/camera_3` and  `/camera_4` which are published by 4 client nodes. The 4 topics process are all the same (save received msg into one buffer variable ). Could I bind only one callback to 4 `rclcpp::Subscription` objects? Thanks for your  help a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411201/the-same-msg-type-of-multiple-topic-names-can-use-only-one-callback-on-ros2?/) by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2023-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
        m_client_topic_subs_.clear(); //std::vector<rclcpp::SubscriptionBase::SharedPtr> m_client_topic_subs_;
        for(int i = 0; i < client_robots_num; i++){
            auto topic_name = dynamicmap_topic_name + std::to_string(i);
            std::function<void(const nav_interfaces::msg::DynamicMap::SharedPtr)> callback = 
                 std::bind(&DynamicMapManager::dynamicMapCB, this, std::placeholders::_1, topic_name);
            auto sub = m_node->create_subscription<nav_interfaces::msg::DynamicMap>(topic_name, 10, callback);
            m_client_topic_subs_.push_back(sub);
        }
```

callback defination is here, in callback we can print topic_name, it comes from 4 cameras.

```
void DynamicMapManager::dynamicMapCB(const nav_interfaces::msg::DynamicMap::SharedPtr dynamic_map_ptr, const std::string& topic_name)
```

---

Originally posted by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) with karma: 252 on 2023-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can use the same callback function for multiple subscriptions.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2023-01-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2